# Javascript open link multiple times on clicking the button

Tags: javascript

I used this javascript in my head section and when I click the button it always opens targeted link. Here I want to open the link once

```
    <?php
    $onclick = '';
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
        setcookie('visited', '1', time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
        $onclick = 'onclick="window.open(\'https://www.google.com\', \'_blank\')"';
    }
   ?>
```

**Usage**

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> <?php echo $onclick; ?>>
```

I checked its write cookie perfectly but not working..Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Because when you click on the link it does not reload the page. Remember that PHP is a server-side language: the inline JS is already written onto the page when the page is loaded. The PHP script is not re-evaluated when a user clicks on the link. You should use JS instead.

Comment: send the full code, where is `$onclick` used?

Comment: <body <?php body_class(); ?> <?php echo $onclick; ?>> Please check the  usage

Comment: You should use `onload` instead of `onclick`, so it will open instantly. You are not applying the `onclick` to a button. You are applying it to the `body`. That will not work as intended.

Comment: You have onclick in body tag. Shouldn't be that in a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the JS code in the following way

```
 /**
* For writing cookie
* @param name {String} name of the cookie
* @param value {*} value of the cookie
* @param days {Number} number of days
*/
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
var expires = "";
if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
  expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

/**
* Get cookie by a name
* @param name {String}
* @returns {*}
*/
function getCookie(name) {
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
 }
return null;
}

/**
* Check for already redirected or not. If not then redirect to targeted site.
*/
function redirectToTarget() {
 var isAlreadyRedirected = getCookie('redirect');
 if (null === isAlreadyRedirected) {
  setCookie('redirect', 1, 30); // write for 1 month
  window.open('https://www.google.com');
 }
}
```

And call js function from body onclick like the following way

```
<body onclick="redirectToTarget()">
```